# Filter and Create JSON object from plain text using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have following plain text generated from an input source as follows:

1 agri dev ban lt **shortform1** 346 346 343 **343** 9,671 **346** 3,330,659 78 -3.00 -0.87 3.00 0.87 361.80 400.07 449.86 472.00 283.00

2 Api Pwr Cpy **shortform2** 355 355 347 **348** 2,702 **355** 942,793 36 -7.00 -1.97 8.00 2.31 366.09 465.42 479.63 683.00 246.00

Now, I need an array that will contain a JSON object as follows:

```
[
 {
  traded: shortform1,
  close: 343,
  previousClose: 355
 },
 {
  traded: shortform2,
  close: 348,
  previousClose: 355
 }
]
```

Comment: Great, what have you tried so far? What distinguishes the bolded numbers there?

Comment: What did you try to achieve this? Share your code.

Comment: @CertainPerformance : For the numbers, the index position is 4 and 6 i.e. 343 , 355 but for the shortcode the index position varies according to the starting name

Comment: What is this `shortcode` you refer to? Do you mean the `traded` property?

Comment: There is only one JSON object, perhaps you just want an object, or do you want a text string that is valid JSON? Perhaps you should split the string on new lines, then on spaces to parse each line, extract the data you want and format it as an Object, which can be stringified as JSON if you wish or just left as an Object.

Comment: @samcro—the data is in different locations in each line, even the numbers (apparently). The OP must explain the logic for how to parse the string, which would include how to correctly tokenise it and determine the values for *traded*, *close* and *previousClose*, e.g. "ban lt" might be one token, or two. Values might be missing based on some previous value, or the start point might be linked to the first value: 1 -> shortform1, 2 -> shortform2, or the last "word" before the numbers, or the OP could just have incorrectly created the data sample. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the short code is shortform 1 and shortform 2

Comment: @samcro—you're making it worse. The value "shortform 1" doesn't exist in the data, it's "shortform1". You've highlighted 346 as the shortform1 previousClose value, but made it 355 in your sample output. You haven't explained the logic for selecting values from the strings. I've already written a parser to give the result you want, but I can't post it until I know the parsing rules are correct, i.e. until it can be verified as an answer and you've made some attempt yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return one object per line.
I'd hope you can do the rest!

```
function getObject(line)
{
  var splitLine = line.split(' '), offset=parseInt(splitLine[0]);
  return {traded:splitLine[6-offset],close:splitLine[10-offset],previousClose:splitLine[12-offset]}
}
```

edit: just realised shortform isn't always in the same place. I've updated the code to fix this but it's just a guess because you haven't provided enough information

Comment: "*… just realised shortform isn't always in the same place*". Indeed.

Comment: @awfullyawful shortform is not always at the same place

Comment: I know that samcro, the code handles that by making use of the first character and adjusting accordingly. If that's not right then you need to provide more information because it works perfectly for the two examples you've given.